# Angular js dynamic template as per route parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is my route code

```
.state('app.single', {
    url: "/playlists/:playlistId",
    views: {
        'menuContent': {
            templateUrl: "templates/playlist.html",
            controller: 'PlaylistCtrl'
        }
    }
});
```

What I am going to do is:

```
.state('app.single', {
    url: "/playlists/:playlistId",
    views: {
        'menuContent': {
            templateUrl: "templates/**<< :playlistId >>**.html",
            controller: 'PlaylistCtrl'
        }
    } 
});
```

How can I do this approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
.state('app.single', {
url: "/playlists/:playlistId",
views: {
  'menuContent': {
    templateUrl: function(params) {
       return 'templates/' + params.playlistId + '.html' ;
    }
    controller: 'PlaylistCtrl'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> Here is what you want.

```
views: {
    'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: function($stateParams) {
            return "templates/" + $stateParams.playlistId + ".html";
        },
        controller: 'PlaylistCtrl'
  }
}
```

> **Is it good practice?**

The answer is no.

You are directly passing route parameter value to generate template url but this will cause break application UI if user supplies wrong route parameter.

Better way is to use switch case to generate template url.

```js
     views: {
       'menuContent': {
         templateUrl: function($stateParams) {
           var param = 0;
           switch ($stateParams.playlistId) {
             case 1:
               param = 1;
               break;
             case 2:
               param = 2;
               break;
             default:
               param = 0
           }
           return "templates/" + param + ".html";
         },
         controller: 'PlaylistCtrl'
       }
     }
```

Comment: hi I am just a beginner , I cant understand your second method I will go with your first method, seems its working, thanks

Comment: second method is just using switch case based on playlistId, if playlist id is wrong, then it will set default id to avoid breaking your application

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `stateParams` for this:

```
views: {
    'menuContent': {
        // Inject $stateParams to access the playlistId parameter
        templateUrl: ["$stateParams", function ($stateParams) { 
            return "templates/" + $stateParams.playlistId + ".html";
        }],
        controller: 'PlaylistCtrl'
  }
}
```